# How to detect if selected text is in an editable area?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey, userscripts

### The coder's fantasy

I created a simple user script to act very quickly on the text I selected. It goes like this:

1. I select a word, a website (doesn't have to be a link), or a phrase from, let's say, a `p` element
2. When I press the trigger key, the algorithm will try to figure out if it's a website or text. It will open a tab: if it's a website, that's what it'll load; if it's text, it will google it.

### The problem shows its ugly head

It works great except when I'm editing text. If I'm editing something I've written in a `textarea`/`input` it will fire, potentially losing what I wrote. Fortunately, there's usually cache, or even the site will warn me for having unsaved changes, which saves me from losing whatever I wrote. But it's something to fix.

### The challenge

The userscript should only run on text that can't be edited. You'd think it is as easy as not calling the function if the selected text is within a `textarea`. But there are many ways to display editable content without using classical elements. The "best" filter I've found is to check for `document.activeElement.isContentEditable`. However, in this very box, that returns `false`. This is a `textarea` element, so I can add it to the filter, and I can do so with a few more I can think of. But apart from being an ugly solution, it is not foolproof.

Besides adding a "did you run me by accident?" prompt, is there a better way to do this?

Edit: [my current code](https://gist.github.com/nmaxcom/80cb59fc7566181a4b923e5983683693)

Comment: My hacky solution in a similar user script was to check for keyboard input. I showed the "did you run me by accident?" prompt only when there were multiple key press events on the page. Multiple key presses indicate that something was written by the user. I excluded some keys, e.g. enter, escape and ctrl/alt/shift + key combinations. This worked well on static websites.

Comment: So you would be listening all the time for keypresses, right? It's not super elegant but it could be the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly .... here is an example of how to go about it.

```js
if (['TEXTAREA', 'INPUT'].includes(document.activeElement.nodeName)) {
  // it is in textarea, input
}
else if (document.activeElement.isContentEditable) {
  // it is in contentEditable element
}
else {
  // not above
}
```

Above is not the only method, e.g. the following using `window.getSelection()`:

```js
const sel = window.getSelection();
const text = sel.toString();

if (!text.trim()) {
  // there is no selection
  // or selection is white-space
  // or selection is in textarea, input
}
else if (document.activeElement.isContentEditable) {
  // it is in contentEditable element
}
else {
  // not above
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very similar to what I have going [but yours is better so I'm stealing that :)], but does it cover all use cases? Now I can't find an example, but I've sometimes seen people using div or span elements editable with some JS framework's help and `isContentEditable` returning false. Maybe I should try to send a character and somehow check if it "got through"...? I was expecting a foolproof method.

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea That should cover all the usual cases but it can be adapted further when the need arises. If you have examples of such edge cases, let me know and I will update the reply. I am going to update the reply with more info as well.

Comment: I updated the post with the code I'm using

Comment: I can think of an outlier. Using custom element which has `textarea` or `input` inside causes it's still editable but the nodeName is not 'INPUT' or 'TEXTAREA' but a customized tag name.